# Google Fusion Table, Cannot seem to convert markers into polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Right now, the code below is giving me red markers, where I want to apply Fusion Table styling with polygons. The link below is the optimal solution I want.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-styling

With geocodezip's help, I'm getting a good alternative with querying marker colors for the numbers (CNASD).  But now, all of the markers now default to green with the code below.  I'm certain CNASD is part of the table, but why it would not be available I do not know.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var map, layer;

function initialize() {

  var usa = new google.maps.LatLng(40.4230, -98.7372);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: usa,
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: '"FULL ADDRESS',
      from: '1wwaFO4DnqwX_8YQQwn2U2v6ZQ1ygcololTkFUr4'
    },
    styles: [{
        markerOptions: {
       iconName: 'small_red'
      }
    }, {
      where: 'CNASD == 6',
        markerOptions: {
        iconName: 'small_green'
      }
    }]
  });
  layer.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: `believe the problem is that the Fusion Tables SQL API is no longer available, so I can't use these queries anymore.` that isn't true.

Comment: Hm.  Well I'm at a loss for leads then.  I guess it's either something wrong with my code or I'm trying to fit too much data into polygons.

Comment: I don't see any Polygons in your table.  Only addresses, which will result in markers.  None of the code above matches your table (I don't see columns with name 'Reg' or 'Days'.  If you want to style the markers, use [markerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesMarkerOptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries are not valid for your table.  Your table doesn't contain any polygons. To style the markers use markerOptions:

```
function initialize() {

  var usa = new google.maps.LatLng(40.4230, -98.7372);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: usa,
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: '"FULL ADDRESS',
      from: '1wwaFO4DnqwX_8YQQwn2U2v6ZQ1ygcololTkFUr4'
    },
    styles: [{
      markerOptions: {
        iconName: 'small_blue'
      }
    }]
  });
  layer.setMap(map);
}
```

[example with "blue" markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_MarkerStyling.html)

It looks like all your rows contains zip codes.  If you really want polygons, you could merge with a table containing the ZCTA polygons, like this one:

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1fzwSGnxD0xzJaiYXYX66zuYvG0c5wcEUi5ZI0Q#

Comment: Well the markers are blue now, but I wanted polygons.  How do I go about doing that?  I don't see that in the icon set.  Thank you for your solution though; it's certainly an alternative I could use.

Comment: What polygons to you want?  You need to use a table that contains them.  You might need to merge a table with the polygons in it with your list of localities.  See the documentation for information on how to do that.

Comment: Going with your solution, I've tried querying the below, but it seems every marker wants to default to green.

'    styles: [{
      markerOptions: {
        iconName: 'small_red'
      }
    }, {
      where: 'CNASD == 6',
     markerOptions: {
        iconName: 'small_green'
      }
    }]
  });'  Sorry about the formatting.  Trying to figure this 'code' out.

Comment: Probably better to update the question with the code rather than placing it in the comments.  I don't see a column in your table with the name 'CNASD'.

Comment: All right.  I gotta go home now for today, but thanks for all of your help.

Comment: The correct syntax for the query would be 'CNAS = 6' (not ==), but currently there are no values in that column.  I updated my version of the table and that works for me.